# Right Voltage, still not charging

Tags: laptop, voltage, charger

My charger died a bit ago and even after ordering a new one with the exact same Voltage (19.5v) and Amps (4.62a), the laptop does not charge. Is there something that needs troubleshooting, or has something been damaged?

Comment: Can you verify the voltage in your question and double-check what's listed on your laptop and old charger?  No laptop runs on 1.5V, so if that's what your new charger puts out, that would explain your problem.  Also, what is the make and model of the laptop (and is the replacement charger OEM)?  Some laptop brands check for an OEM charger.

Comment: @fixer1234, that's interesting, how do they do that? I had assumed a charger shouldn't be able to transmit a digital signature, since it's supposed to provide stable voltage.

Comment: Yes, it slipped my mind that it was actually 19.5v, not 1.5v. Both chargers read the exact same for their output and input. The laptop is a Dell Latitude E4130, and the replacement was exactly what it recommended I buy.

Comment: @Aprillomat, There are several ways to do it, depending on the number of wires in the connector.  I believe Dell uses a digital signature over a third wire in the connector.  With extra contacts, another approach is to simply bias one of the extra contacts.

Comment: The charger may be defective.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the obvious: Connector. But if it fits, then there shouldn't be anything else besides voltage and amps.

This to me sounds like there's something more to it. Is your laptop able to power up from the charger without the battery in? If that's the case, the charge circuitry could be at fault, or the battery itself.

Comment: The new charger is an exact identical model and everything, both labels read the same voltage and amps. When it starts up it states something like that the voltage and amps could not be determined, and the battery has never shown any faulty signs before. Apologies, the voltage is actually 19.5v, not 1.5v.